# Where can I find an Angular event reference for $on?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've learned about angular events $destroy, $contentViewLoaded and such which are very handy. However I can't for the life of me find a reference of all angularjs events. I want to make a directive without a template but still senses certain events like mouse click and such.

What are all the built in angular events that $on can listen to?

Comment: Are you looking for a list of events like this http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/events.html ?

Comment: No, I want to know all the built in angular events that $on can listen to

Comment: If an angular provider/service/whatever emits events they will be listed per page in the docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service (ctrl+f for the events section, usually at the bottom)

Comment: `$on` is documented in the [AngularJS $rootScope API Reference -- $on](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on). I don't think there is a comprehensive list of `$on`  events because any directive or controller (even your controllers) can `$emit` a custom event.